# Simple Cursor Adapter problem

Tags: android, listview, android-widget, simplecursoradapter

Here is my code for a simple cursor adapter.

```
public class CursorList extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    DatabaseAdapter da = new DatabaseAdapter(this, "mydb.sqlite");

    da.open();
    Cursor cur = da.fetchAllRecords("Doctors", new String[]{"FirstName"});
    startManagingCursor(cur);

    cur.moveToFirst();
    do {
        Log.v("Info", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("FirstName")));
    } while(cur.moveToNext());

    cur.moveToFirst();

    String[] from = new String[]{"FirstName"};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.row};

    SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_item, cur, from, to);

    setListAdapter(sca);
    }
}
```

The data records are displayed correctly in the log, but the code stops working when it reaches the

```
SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_item, cur, from, to);
```

line.

The error I get is :

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26746): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26746): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.arnab.cursorlist/com.arnab.cursorlist.CursorList}:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

Where am I going wrong?

Why does it give an error that column '_id' doesn't exist? Is it a necessary column which we have to have in our tables?

EDIT:

When I put the cursor related code in a try catch block, something like this:

```
try {
        SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_item, cur, from, to);

        setListAdapter(sca);
    }
    catch(Exception E) {
        Log.v("Error", E.getMessage());
    }
```

I get the message :

```
VERBOSE/Error(1026): column '_id' does not exist
```

@Rasel : Here is the `fetchAllRecords` method

```
public Cursor fetchAllRecords(String table, String columns[]) {
    return mDb.query(table, columns, null, null, null, null, null);     
}
```

Comment: yea! `_id` is column which is you should have in your table, instead of your usual `id`s like `employee_id`, `student_id` or `product_id`. You have just to replace such ids with `_id` as the Android Sqlite db is managed through `_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does it give an error that column '_id' doesn't exist? Is it a necessary column which we have to have in our tables?

Yes, if you want to use your database information in a cursor adapter.  The adapter uses it for internal purposes.  Your table must have an '_id' column, and you must select it in your query (so it is in the `Cursor` result set).  You do not have to actually display it in your `ListView`.

**Revised for Posterity**

Instead of actually adding the '_id' column, you can `SELECT` your own 'id' column as '_id', and it will work just the same.

Comment: What if I have an existing database which I am using in other applications too. I would be really hesitant to change the column name. Is there any way out? I do have an 'id' column. Would that help?

Comment: I've never seen anybody mention a way to get around it.  You could always, instead of changing a column name, add a new column called _id and make it INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT.  You don't actually have to use it, but the adapters need it for reference.

Comment: You made me curious, so to expand on my answer, here (http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java) is the source for the `CursorAdapter` class.  There are two references to the "_id" column that you could probably change without any adverse consequences and then extend `CursorAdapter` to make your own adapter.  I'm not sure how many other classes you'd have to copy to make them work, but it could be an alternate solution for you if you think it's worth investigating.  Good luck! :)

Comment: Or you might try running a `rawQuery()` to query your database and using `SELECT id as _id, column2, column3...`, which would be a much easier solution.  I'm not sure how that would work though.

Comment: I tried the raw query. It worked. Even  `mDb.query(tablename, new String[]{"student_id as _id", "FirstName"}, null, null, null, null, null);` worked! Thanks for the help. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Write Cursor related code in try catch block.Your problem will be solved.Check when created table you typed different column rather than '_id'

Comment: why is the problem even there though?

Comment: I put it in a try catch block. The exception message generated is : VERBOSE/Error(1026): column '_id' does not exist

Comment: See your code where you wrote query to retrieve values.you are trying to do something with column _id .But while creating table you didn't give the name _id

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the table _id in the projection. the list cursor adapter needs the _id to keep track of the rows. you don't have to actually display it anywhere or use it but the cursor needs to contain that column. also a primary key column named _id is mandatory in every android table.

Comment: What do you mean by mandatory? Say I'm not using a SimpleCursorAdapter, do I still need to have the '_id' column in my tables?