# error with sample adapter class

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

based on this example [Simple Cursor Adapter problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660072/simple-cursor-adapter-problem)
I think the error is something todo with the xml layouts

database details:

```
 public static final String question = "quest";
  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "QuestionDB";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "questions";
   DBAdapter da = new DBAdapter(this);

 // open the database connection
da.open();
// assign to the cursor the ability to loop through the records.
Cursor c = da.getAllContacts();
```

the method getAllContacts(); is based on this code below

```
  public Cursor getAllContacts() 
  {
         return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
   question, possibleAnsOne,possibleAnsTwo,  possibleAnsThree,realQuestion}, null,   null, null, null, null);
}

startManagingCursor(c);

// move to the first element
c.moveToFirst();


 String[] from = new String[]{"quest"};
 int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name_entry };

 SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.layout_list_example, c, from, to);
 setListAdapter(sca);
```

Here are the xml files layout_list_example.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_example_entry.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="28dip" />
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number_entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="28dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

extended contents setting the content review removed that problem. I will remember that for the future. I had to change the column back to quest as it said no column existed and when i ran the activity i got a black screen with lines across i guess a list view with no data.

Here is the error log

```
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{alex.android.basic.databse.questions/alex.android.basic.databse.questions.Result}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'question' does not exist
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'question' does not exist
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:267)
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:332)
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:81)
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at alex.android.basic.databse.questions.Result.onCreate(Result.java:37)
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-12 19:52:22.570: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

Comment: Did setting the content view help?

Comment: You have data in your cursor or you wouldn't have blank lines, you're just not calling them out properly (or or they're empty strings).  I do know that the contents of your `from` array **must** be the names of columns you pulled in your cursor...

Comment: OK so since its blank i am not calling some correctly. Is there anyway i can narrow it down. I can provide the column name that i want to return from the database class

Comment: We need to see your SQL where you create the table.

Comment: Updated my answer, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect  `String[] from = new String[]{"quest"};`

That String[] needs to be the name of one of the columns in your cursor, as it is used to map data from your cursor to the listview.

I think you want this:

```
String[] from = new String[]{"question"};
```

EDIT

If it can't find that then I would guess that you need to set the content view fir the activity.

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_list_example);
```

EDIT 2

I think we've been staring at it without seeing it...  in your query, enclose each item in quotes except for the KEY_ one.  "question", etc.

Comment: sadly that didnt fix my problem. The error is "Your content must have a ListView whos id attribute is android.R.id.list" the error is in quotation marks

Comment: If it complained about a row, that won't help as that's a column.  What was the exact error?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ListActivty` your layout xml should have listview with the id `android:id="@android:id/list"`

For ex:

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

So changing `android:id="@android:id/android:list"` in your `layout_list_example.xml` with `android:id="@android:id/list"` should fix your problem

Hope this helps

Comment: I made the change but I am still getting the error Do you have any idea what could still be wrong

Comment: are you getting the same error?  you should edit your question and post your log cat

Comment: the first part of my post talks about the problem with column. I have added the output of what triggers the error

Comment: Did you create column 'question' in your database properly? if so try uninstall/reinstall your app. Because it says column 'question' does not exist. Maybe first time you create your database you may be forgot to create the column 'question', editing your sql to create database will not called after first creating your database