# How to retrieve data from SQLite Database and display on ListView for Java Android Application

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

So I have a database created on another page and it is working. Now I am trying to retrieve the data from SQLite database and display on the ListView on an android application.

I have wrote a code for it but apparently it crashes every time I try to view. Please advise

I wanted to to run in a way like this
Register -> Login->View empty listview-> Add Records-> View listview with records that was added

Updated Crash Log:

```
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.manandhowproject/mdad.project.Medrecord}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:168)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:145)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:91)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:104)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at mdad.project.Medrecord.onCreate(Medrecord.java:34)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
01-29 20:42:19.971: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     ... 11 more
```

MedRecords.java

```
package mdad.project;

import com.example.manandhowproject.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Medrecord extends Activity {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ListView lvMedRec;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    Cursor cursor;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.medrecord);
    createDatabase();
    Cursor c = null;
    c = db.rawQuery("select * from MedRecords",null);String[] from = new String[]{"Bodytemp","HeartRate","BMI"};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.etBodyTemp, R.id.etHeartRate, R.id.etBMI};
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.medrecord,c,from,to,0);

    ListView lvMedRec = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMedRec);
    lvMedRec.setAdapter(adapter);


    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick (View V){

        Intent msg5 = new Intent(Medrecord.this, Addorupdate.class);
        startActivity(msg5);
        }
    });

    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick (View V){

        Intent msg6 = new Intent(Medrecord.this, Addorupdate.class);
        startActivity(msg6);
        }
    });

    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignOut);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick (View V){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Log Out Success ! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent msg7 = new Intent(Medrecord.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(msg7);
        }
    });
}

 protected void createDatabase(){
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("MedRec",Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MedRecords(recld integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, Bodytemp text, HeartRate text, BMI text;");

    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fourth, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Please add the crash log too.

Comment: @DataDino Hi the crash log has been added

Answer (score 0):

Yeah looks a SQL syntax error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

It's saying you don't have a '_id' column and it's probably coming from where you are creating a SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.medrecord,c,from,to,0);
```

See this question: [Simple Cursor Adapter problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660072/simple-cursor-adapter-problem)

The fix is to add the '_id' column into your cursor. But you are already adding everything ('*') to your cursor, so it should be there right?

Well it would be except that you created an explicit primary key in your table called 'recld' which means that your table will not have the built in '_id' column.

Anyways, use the '_id' column for primary key.

```
protected void createDatabase(){
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("MedRec",Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MedRecords(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, Bodytemp text, HeartRate text, BMI text);");
}
```

Comment: Hey, I tried updating the createDatabase(), however it still crashes. Please Advise thanks

Comment: Must be a different crash; post it.

Comment: Hi I have updated the crash log, please advise thanks

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the query.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MedRecords(recld integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, Bodytemp text, HeartRate text, BMI text);");
```

also why are you using autoincrement?

UPDATE:

Also you are trying to use cursor which REQUIRES a column called "_id". Edit your table creation statement.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MedRecords(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, Bodytemp text, HeartRate text, BMI text);");
```

Answer (score 0):

Cursor adapters require that the cursor has a column named **_id** (*the error you have experienced*) and this should be the unique identifier which all tables, unless the `WITHOUT ROWID` phrase is used in the table's creation, have.

This unique identifier is a special normally hidden column called **rowid**. Coding `?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `??INTEGER PRIMARAY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` creates an alias for the rowid column named ?? (where ?? is a valid column name).

As such you could use your existing table using the **`AS`** keyword when extracting the cursor. e.g. changing :-

`c = db.rawQuery("select * from MedRecords",null);String[] from = new String[]{"Bodytemp","HeartRate","BMI"};`

to

**`c = db.rawQuery("select rowid AS _id,* from MedRecords",null);String[] from = new String[]{"Bodytemp","HeartRate","BMI"};`**

would result in a cursor that has the **_id** column and all other columns from the **MedRecords** table.

Alternately, as **recld** is an alias of the rowid you could use :-

**`c = db.rawQuery("select recld AS _id,* from MedRecords",null);String[] from = new String[]{"Bodytemp","HeartRate","BMI"};`**

Again you would have an _id column as well as all other columns including the **recld** column in the Cursor.

---

There also appears to be an issue with the table creation SQL in that the trailing closing parenthesis is missing so instead of :-

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MedRecords(recld integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, Bodytemp text, HeartRate text, BMI text;");
```

you should have :-

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MedRecords(recld integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, Bodytemp text, HeartRate text, BMI text);");
```

However, changing the above will not change the table if it already exists (which appears to be the case). If the data can be lost then before running the changes made according to the above you should delete the App's data or uninstall the App.

If the data you currently have is needed then have a good read of [ALTER TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) and especially the section entitled ***Making Other Kinds Of Table Schema Changes***

---

### Notes

- Coding `AUTOINCREMENT` is rarely required, it does not change the column to automatically generating a unique id(rowid). Coding `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` does that. What `AUTOINCREMENT` does is guarantee that the unique id(rowid) will be greater that the last generated. It does this by using an additional table named sqlite_sequence to store that last used unique identifier at additional cost. The SQLite documentation states :-

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.

---

### Further Information

- [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)
- [Rowid Tables](https://sqlite.org/rowidtable.html)